# Imagefields inside of a Django ManyToManyField Have Wrong URLs

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, sorl-thumbnail

All my `Imagefields` in my app return their `urls` correctly, except for these `BaseImages` that are nested inside a `ManyToManyField`.

They get returned as partial URLS like `/media/uploads/img.png` instead of `http://localhost:8000/media/uploads/img.png`

```
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField
class BaseImage(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    width = models.IntegerField()
    height = models.IntegerField()

    image = ImageField(upload_to='uploads/')

class ImagePost(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    images = models.ManyToManyField(BaseImage)
```

--

```
# settings.py
MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users/Jacob/Documents/Projects/project_media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}

"""
SORL THUMBNAIL
"""
THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = True
```

These work just fine and return something like `http://localhost:8000/media/uploads/img.png`:

```
from sorl.thumbnail import ImageField

class User(...):
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/')

class Group(...):
    display_image = ImageField(uplaod_to='uploads/')
```

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: @KlausD. Edited my question. The nested ImageFields get returned as partial URL's instead of full ones. Image fields elsewhere don't have this problem.

Comment: How are you using the images? Please post the template code where you are trying to render them. Also note that what you describe as partial URLs (`/media/uploads/img.png`) are perfectly valid URLs and would work in the browser.

Comment: @solarissmoke yeah, but all of my other imagefields are returning full url– even if they're valid I'd like for them to be consistent. I'm not using them in templates– I'm using django-rest-framework imagefield serializers, but even just calling imagefield.url in the shell returns that url

Comment: `ImageField.url` does not add a hostname to the URL - it just prefixes the image path with `MEDIA_URL`. From the code you have posted there is no explanation for this - I can only suggest that there is code you haven't posted which is modifying this behaviour for one of your models/serializers.